# Creating array of objects dynamically based on length

Tags: javascript

I have the length of my previous object and i need to create a new array of objects based on the length with new key's.

```
Length = 3;

var newArray = [];
for(var i =0; i <3; i++){
    var Object = {};
    Object['newKey'] = 1;
    newArray.push(Object);
}
```

This would eventually create newArray of Objects whose length is 3 containing something like this.. `newArray[0],[1],[2]`.

Am i doing this correctly, please do suggest me if anything wrong or a better way to do this.

Comment: Well, I see some problems/ways in which it could be improved...

Comment: @Jared Farrish: could you suggest me over this

Comment: Well, first of all, when you say `{}`, you're creating an object, so that step/line is superfluous.

Comment: And don't use Capitalized var names. "Object" is a class (in fact the base class of everything in JavaScript), so it's not a good idea to suddenly redeclare it to be... well, an instance of itself. (Length doesn't conflict with anything, but still - "length" is preferred.) In javascript, variables should be camelCase.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to accomplish here? As in why you're doing this? There might be a better way to go about what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you wrote (I think), just shortened a bit (and fixed the capitalization of variable names)

```
var length = 3;
var newArray = [];
for( var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ) {
    newArray.push({newKey: 1});
}
```

but to be honest it's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You could make it slightly more dynamic by referencing the variable for length.

Example updated per comments:

```
var length = 3,
    newArray = [];

for ( var i=0; i<length; i++ ) {
    var tempObj = {};
    tempObj['newKey'] = 'SomeValue';
    newArray.push(tempObj);
}
```

I didn't really do more than clean up what you have.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, so this will put the same object in each index of the array.  I don't think this is what the OP wants.  You should put `tempObj = {};` inside the loop.

Comment: Won't work right. You're only creating 1 object, and then referencing that object multiple times in the array (edit: mVChr beat me to it)